# Spring application doesn't print exceptions correctly: FatalBeanException not found

Tags: java, spring

While debugging Spring application, instead of getting verbose `BeanCreationException` messages, I am getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
```

dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

is in the POM.

**UPDATE**

`mvn dependency:tree` includes the following:

```
...
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.38:compile
[INFO] +- com.opencsv:opencsv:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.controlsfx:controlsfx:jar:8.40.10:compile
...
```

Comment: What is your `spring.version` and add the output of `mvn dependency:tree`. Apparently the spring classes cannot be found (or you have too little information in your question).

Comment: Spring version is `4.2.5.RELEASE`.

Comment: @M.Deinum see my update please for dependency tree

Comment: Post the full stack trace instead of a snippet, the same would apply to your output as that seems to be cut-off as well.

Answer (score 0):

check the classpath ,may caused  by other error.show the full stack strace

```
@Service
public class Test {

public Test(){
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test=new Test();
}
}

public class NoClassDefFoundErrorDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // The following line would throw ExceptionInInitializerError
        SimpleCalculator calculator1 = new SimpleCalculator();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    // The following line would cause NoClassDefFoundError
    SimpleCalculator calculator2 = new SimpleCalculator();
}

}

class SimpleCalculator{
  static int undefined = 1 / 0;
}
```